# How can I plot pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I would like to plot pytorch gpu tensor:

```
input= torch.randn(100).to(device)
output = torch.where(input>=0, input, -input)

input = input.('cpu').detach().numpy().copy()
output = output.('cpu').detach().numpy().copy()

plt.plot(input,out)
```

However I try to convert those tensors into cpu, numpy, it does not work. How can I plot the tensors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
plt.plot(input.cpu().numpy(),output.cpu().numpy())
```

Alternatively you can try,

```
plt.plot(input.to('cpu').numpy(),output.to('cpu').numpy())
```

Comment: Thank you. But they say 'can't convert non-cpu tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.'

Comment: Hi @JennyRowland , I updated my answer, does that work?

Comment: plt.plot() accepts numpy arrays. The are sequence of operations to perform. First, assuming the tensor is on device(GPU), you need to copy it to CPU first by using .cpu(). Then the you need to change the data type from tensors to numpy by using .numpy(). so, it should be (a.cpu().numpy()).

Comment: FYI, I use `output.numpy(Force=True)` for this. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.numpy.html